# How to set token on login and reset on logout react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, token

I am having an issue with token.
I am able to get token from the backend, but I am unable to go to dashboard page ("/dashboard") after login ("/").
And I also want that after clicking to logout to reset token and return to main page.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname === '/' && sessionStorage.getItem('token') !== undefined) {
      console.log('Resetting token');
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', undefined);
    }
  }, [location.pathname, authContext.token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authContext.token !== undefined) {
      authContext.user = user;
      authContext.token = token;
      authContext.validToken = true;

      navigate("/dashboard");
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [authContext.token, navigate]);
```

I think it is the best that start page listens when it returns to her.

Comment: Looks like `authContext` is not being set properly

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the condition to check if the token is null or an empty string.
Try the code below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.pathname === '/' && !sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
    console.log('Resetting token');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
}, [location.pathname]);
```

Comment: It works great to return to the main page, but it won't login, can you help me with that also?

Comment: I have solved your problem. If you need to ask anything, just post it so everyone can solve it together